# Is there a silverlight equivalent of swfObject.js?

Tags: silverlight

Is there a Silverlight equivalent of swfObject.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yep. silverlight.js comes with silverlight SDK

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838126(v=vs.95).aspx